# How can I set a custom-default value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, default-value

Im trying to set a default value for a field into a SQL Server Table.
This field is int, and when I go to the GUI and I set Associated Default Value to 0 and I save  the table, than the default value will be ((0)) (and when I insert a record it get the NULL value).

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show the *exact* insert statement that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending NULL.

If you want it to use the default, then don't specify it or use the keyword DEFAULT

```
INSERT (col1, col3) -- col2 is skipped, gets zero default
VALUE (foo, bar)

INSERT (col1, col2, col3)
VALUE (foo, DEFAULT, bar)

INSERT -- not best practice
VALUE (foo, DEFAULT, bar)
```

Comment: No, I'm not sending NULL, I just don't send nothing! Also tried with DEFAULT, but it doesnt work (it always get NULL) :O

Comment: @markzzz: then, you **don't** have a default. *Check* before you refute me please

Comment: @markzzz To make things clear for everyone, post your create table code and your insert code.

Comment: Yeah...I was sending NULL! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I just created a table as follows and the default value on testid2 works as expected.

```
USE [db]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table_1]    Script Date: 01/31/2012 10:27:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
[testid] [int] NULL,
[testid2] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_1_testid2]  DEFAULT ((0))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If you right click on your table, Script Table as..., CREATE TO and then check your result against mine.

Answer (score 0):

If it inserts NULL is because you are probably specifying the column name on the query.

If you do:

insert into table (defaultColumn) values (NULL)

it will ignore the default constraint and insert NULL

There are several scenarios. Try posting your query so we can analyze it